# Is there a shorter way in JavaScript to trigger a function before and on resize?

Tags: javascript

Here is an example of what I mean.

```
function x() {
    return ($(window).width() < 768) ? $('body').addClass('z') : $('body').removeClass('z')
}

function y() {
    x()

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        x()
    })
}
```

Comment: `x(); $(window).on('resize', x);`…? This is about as short as it gets.

Comment: You want to have your function called *before* the resize ? You mean before the DOM changes when the user just asked for a resize ?

Comment: you need to elaborate more on the exact requirement and scenario for what you want it.

Comment: @DenysSéguret No, I want to check for something as soon as I call y(), and call this something when the user resizes the browser window as well.

Comment: Then yes, you have to explicitly call `x` once and also attach it to the `resize` event. There's no real other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like invoke function before attached to `window resize` event you can manually invoke `resize` during attachment:

```
$(window).on('resize', x).trigger('resize');
```

But downside of this approach is that you not only fire `x` function but you create fake `resize` event (it can be problematic in some scenarios).